# Where is Dictionary<,>.SetCapacity(int newCapacity)?

Tags: .net, dictionary

If I want to add lots of items to a `Dictionary` at once and I know the (rough) number in advance, it's both faster and more efficient in terms of memory and cpu if I set the initial capacity using the appropriate constructor overload.

In the case I tested, using 300.000 entries, if I set the capacity of the Dictionary to, say, 300.000, it is about 25% faster than when left uninitialized.

Now what can I do if I have an **already constructed, emptied Dictionary** that I need to fill with lots of items? Assume this is e.g. a `readonly` variable that I cannot reassign with a new Dictionary instance. I don't see anything that influences the capacity of an already constructed Dictionary in the documentation. Something like e.g. a `Clear(int newInitialCapacity)` would be nice.

Am I out of luck?

Comment: What is wrong with using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk84bxf4.aspx) contructor to specify the initial size?

Comment: @TimSchmelter He already has a dictionary constructed and wants to re-use it I think.

Comment: The only way possible to simulate `Clear(int capacity)` would be to invoke `private void Initialize(int capacity)` via reflection.

Comment: @webnoob: Yes, i see the last note now.  However, if it's possible to reassign it and efficiency matters he should simply use the constructor. That's more efficient than using `Clear` and then change the capacity(which is a private method anyway).

Comment: Seems to me really strange case, you are using readonly dictionary, which instantiation you cannot influence. If it is not for educational purposes what is a real-world case you have? Just curious.

Comment: Why not just instantiate a new `Dictionary` specifying your constructor?

Comment: @SergeyS `readonly` has a couple of benefits, like making the object itself usable as a lockObj, not having to check for null etc. Apart from that, just assume you are in that situation, as you might be using a library you can't change or code you don't want to change.

Comment: @EugeneBeresovksy *not having to check for null etc* Uh... `private readonly IDictionary<int, int> _dontHaveToCheckForNull = null;` and what does *like making the object itself usable as a lockObj* even mean? You can `lock` on "normal" objects just fine.

Comment: @EugeneBeresovksy Do you get the performance benefits you require when you initialize all dictionaries to a size large enough to cope with any of the sample data? I'm not sure if a dictionary would shrink if you removed items, so pre-initializing to "full size" might be a workaround.

Comment: What about creating a new dictionary with reserved space and then union with the old one?

Comment: @EugeneBeresovksy Looking at ILSpy I'd have to say that leppie's answer is the closest to what you want, but if you go down the reflection route, you could arguably use reflection against your readonly dictionary to set it, as readonly isn't honored in reflection. At least then you'd be coding against your own private implementation as opposed to Microsoft's.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: There is no guarantee the original instance is not being referenced directly elsewhere.

Comment: @leppie True, but the OP may have visibility of this so I'll leave it as an option.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Good idea. And in hindsight it's so obvious it makes me wonder why I didn't think of it... If I hardcode the `initialCapacity`, it would not be generic (depending on the use case, Dictionary can be 300k entries, or only 1k), ie a bit of a waste of memory for the 1k case, but then again, that is the way it is right now! Only it's reversed: it's unfair to the 300k case. I could even make it overridable. So it's a(n embarrassingly obvious) workaround in cases where you can change the constructor call(s).

Comment: @iamsleepy I want to get the data into the existing `Dictionary` instance, which btw is emptied, as I stated, so `Union` would be a no-op anyway.

Comment: @EugeneBeresovksy Hopefully this will solve the problem for the immediate future for you. Another alternative, albeit one not usually taken lightly, is to implement your own dictionary that allows you to grab size chunks using a special method. There might be an open source collections library you can use as a basis (decompiling the actual `Dictionary<>` would likely go against some sort of license). Did you try leppie's suggestion?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I +1ed leppie's suggestion, because it does show it way. But I was (in addition to fixing my issue, thanks for your help btw) looking for an official and future-proof way, like the one outlined in my own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the answer is: **Yes, I am out of luck. An already constructed Dictionary's capacity cannot be changed**, well except of course incrementally by adding elements one by one.

If only .net's `Dictionary` had an `AddAll(..)` method akin to **Java's [putAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll%28java.util.Map%29)**, then I could leave it up to the smarts of the `Dictionary` implementer.

Answer (score -1):

You state "Don't see anything that influences the capacity of an already constructed Dictionary in the documentation".

According to the documentation the capacity is not reset on clear.

[Dictionary.Clear Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5txwy7s.aspx)

> The Count property is set to 0, and references to other objects from
>   elements of the collection are also released. The capacity remains
>   unchanged.

You have a dictionary that you are filling with over 300,000 items and performance tuning and you do not have the option to new a dictionary?

Might be worth checking out KeyCollection as you can override ClearItems.

[KeyedCollection.ClearItems Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132450.aspx)

On HashSet there is a TrimExcess.

[HashSet.TrimExcess Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb468758.aspx)